# Do you need a boot loader to install Windows and mulltiple linux distros on one computer?

Tags: operating-systems, multi-boot

I usually dualboot Windows and Ubuntu, but I am getting a new laptop and I plan to install Windows, Ubuntu and other distros (might try arch for example) on the harddrive. Do I need to install a custom boot loader to do that? The old tutorials which I find suggest that I might need to do something like that, but on the other hand Ive never had to do that to dualboot Windows and Ubuntu as long as I install the Windows first.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when using Linux within a dual-boot situation, it's best to install Windows first and then Linux. CentOS and Ubuntu allow you to claim space for the Linux installation away from Windows. In the process, Linux installs a GRUB for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need an appropriate bootloader to install several distros. It must not be "custom": `GRUB` will configure all boot entries for you, and it's installed by every Linux distro automatically!